# DevCenter seems to fail to recognize some CQL cmds

Tags: cassandra-2.0

New to DevCenter and Cassandra, I wonder why my install with DevCenter 1.1.1 and Cassandra 2.0.9 seems to fail to regonize some valid CQL cmdx, like DESCRIBE and COPY from DevCenter when they work fine from CLI CQLSH. DevCenter pops a window saying something like: No viable input near 'COPY'.

Any hints appreciated!

TIA

Comment: :) Seems it'll only do CQL and not CQLSH cmds

Answer (score 0):

Yes. DevCenter doesn't support COPY yet.