# Cassandra DevCenter fails to recognize "COPY" command

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I am trying to run the copy command using DataStax Devcenter. I am using Cassandra 2.0.11 and DevCenter 1.2.1

```
COPY myks.table1 from "D:/test.csv" WITH DELIMITER = ',';
```

But Devcenter fails to recognize the COPY command and keeps giving me error. I can create keyspace, tables, insert values. Any ideas will be appreciated. There is another thread, but it also has no answer. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347859/devcenter-seems-to-fail-to-recognize-some-cql-cmds)

Answer (score 1):

DevCenter does not support COPY, DESCRIBE, SHOW or SUPPORT commands. Use CQLSH instead.